# My entities are not persisting, but I can read from the database fine

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transient

I have just updated to Hibernate 4.1.5 and Spring 3.1.2 (from 2.6ish and 2.5 or something...). I have managed to set everthing up to read from the existing database, and all pages display fine, however when submitting data nothing is being persisted to the database. I have set logging to trace level to try and track this problem down, and the transaction comes down to the following 15 lines extracted from my log:

```
DEBUG - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - SessionImpl                    - Opened session at timestamp: 13430582784
TRACE - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - SessionImpl                    - Setting flush mode to: AUTO
TRACE - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - SessionImpl                    - Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
TRACE - org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - AbstractSaveEventListener      - Transient instance of: ic.entities.MyEntity
TRACE - org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener - DefaultPersistEventListener    - Saving transient instance
TRACE - org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - AbstractSaveEventListener      - Saving [ic.entities.MyEntity#<null>]
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - ActionQueue                    - Adding an EntityIdentityInsertAction for [ic.entities.MyEntity] object
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - ActionQueue                    - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityIdentityInsertAction[ic.entities.MyEntity#<delayed:0>]]
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - ActionQueue                    - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
TRACE - org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - UnresolvedEntityInsertActions  - No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[ic.entities.MyEntity#<delayed:0>]]
TRACE - org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - UnresolvedEntityInsertActions  - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
TRACE - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - SessionImpl                    - Closing session
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - LogicalConnectionImpl          - Closing logical connection
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl - JdbcResourceRegistryImpl       - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl@def577d]
TRACE - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - LogicalConnectionImpl          - Logical connection closed
```

I first noticed that it creates a log message: Saving [ic.entities.MyEntity#< null>]. But manually stepping through the code shows that this happens before id generation has occurred, so I guess it's meant to look like this... I thought at first that lines 10 and 11 were errors, but after stepping through the code it seems that these are the only valid code paths which do not throw an exception, yet as can be seen the session closes and no entries are saved... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I use the following code:

**MyService.java**

```
package ic.services;

import ic.entities.MyEntity;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class MyService extends BasicService<MyEntity>
{
    protected MyService()
    {
        super(MyEntity.class);
    }

    public abstract List<MyEntity> getAllByQuery(String query);
}
```

**BasicService.java**

```
package ic.services;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public abstract class BasicService<T extends Serializable>
{
    @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager em;
    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    protected BasicService(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public T getEntity(Object primaryKey)
    {
        return em.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
    }

    public void persist(T entity)
    {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity)
    {
        em.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

**MyEntity.java**

```
package ic.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity 
@Table
public class MyEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String notes;
    private Date submittedDate;
    private boolean enabled;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getSubmittedDate()
    {
        return submittedDate;
    }

    public void setSubmittedDate(Date submittedDate)
    {
        this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
    }

    public String getNotes()
    {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes)
    {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if(obj instanceof MyEntity)
        {
            MyEntity rhs = (MyEntity)obj;
            return rhs.id == this.id;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Long.valueOf(id).hashCode();
    }
}
```

and to call it:

```
@SpringBean MyService myService; //(Using wicket @Springbean)
...
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setEnabled(true);
entity.setNotes("blah");
entity.setSubmittedDate(new Date());
myService.persist(entity);
```

I have web.xml as:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and finally in applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="ic.services" />
</beans>
```

Again, any help would be fantastic. I'm sure it must be something incredibly stupid on my behalf! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding @Transactional to your persist service method.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. I had @Transactional set on MyServiceImpl class (which I forgot to provide), but clearly this doesn't filter through to base classes! Thanks again.