# EntityActionVetoException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting this exception when I'm trying to save (insert) a valid domain object using Grails/GORM.

```
The EntityInsertAction was vetoed.; nested exception is org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityActionVetoException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed.
```

I have been able to find very little information about this error anywhere on the internet.  I've looked at

- [anyone dealing with this error before? (org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityActionVetoException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67054817/715608)
- [My entities are not persisting, but I can read from the database fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11616899/715608)
- the jBoss docs

This is the code that produces the error

```
    @Publisher(Event.PHOTO_CREATED)
    Photo create(Photo photo, boolean triggerHelperBot = true) {
        makePublicKey(photo)
        discardUnapprovedPhotos(photo.person)

        if (photo.originalPhoto == null)  // this is the original photo
            additionalPhotoService.invalidateFacialRecognitionScore(photo.person)

        photo.status = Photo.PENDING

        photo.externalURL = s3Service.storePhoto(photo)
        photo.save(flush: true) /* EXCEPTION IS THROWM HERE */

        if (triggerHelperBot) {
            helperBotService.beginProcessing(photo)
        }

        return photo
    }
```

The `Photo` object is valid and I can save a virtually identical object for the same user without any errors.  It's also consistent and reproducible.  The same JPG will produce this error every time; however, 95% of JPGs never produce this error.  The only difference is the bytes of the JPGs, but the photo binaries are stored in S3. The `Photo` object only contains a URL to the S3 photo binary, and the URLs are valid for both the `Photo` objects that always produce the error and the `Photo` objects that never produce the error.

Full Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed.; nested exception is org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityActionVetoException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:300)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:305)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:241)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:120)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:247)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:164)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:153)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at us.cloudcard.api.Photo.save(Photo.groovy)
    at us.cloudcard.api.Photo.save(Photo.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService.$pub__create(PhotoService.groovy:62)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService.$tt__create(PhotoService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService$_create_closure2.doCall(PhotoService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService.create(PhotoService.groovy)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService$create$6.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService.$tt__createFrom(PhotoService.groovy:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService$_createFrom_closure1.doCall(PhotoService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService.createFrom(PhotoService.groovy)
    at us.cloudcard.api.PhotoService$createFrom$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at us.cloudcard.api.CroppingService.autoCrop(CroppingService.groovy:36)
    at us.cloudcard.api.CroppingService$autoCrop.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotService$_closure3.doCall(HelperBotService.groovy:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1276)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:94)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotService.$tt__doTask(HelperBotService.groovy:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotService$_doTask_closure6.doCall(HelperBotService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotService.doTask(HelperBotService.groovy)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotService$doTask$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at us.cloudcard.api.HelperBotTaskController.save(HelperBotTaskController.groovy:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:121)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityActionVetoException: The EntityInsertAction was vetoed.
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:607)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1347)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.flushSession(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:285)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor342.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:250)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:297)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still haven't found a plain English explanation of this exception, but I have figured out what's going on; and in my case, this exception meant that another entity that was being persisted as part of the same transaction was failing validation and vetoing the transaction.  Hibernate receives low marks for exception clarity on this one.

### Summary:

If your getting this error, there may be an invalid entity that needs to be persisted in order to flush the transaction and it may not be the entity on which you are calling save.  To figure out which entity is invalid try the steps below.

### Detail Debugging Steps:

1. Find the line throwing the exception.  It will be the top line of the innermost exception. If you're using InteliJ, you may need to [expand the stack trace](https://www.evernote.com/l/ABgOHIDx4itOtLDXnMLrWpUNHu7bjC206H8).  For me, the exception was being raised deep in Hibernate on line `298` of `ActionQueue`. See `org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:298)` in the stack trace.
2. Set a breakpoint.
3. Inspect the variables to find the name of the entity which is vetoing the transaction. In my case, I needed to inspect `insert.entityName`.
4. From there, you'll have trace it back to figure out how that entity is being set incorrectly, and that will be unique to your code, but knowing what entity it is should point you in the right direction.  For me, once I knew that the problem was being caused by a `BoundingBox` rather than by the `Photo` I was trying to save, it was pretty easy to identify that the service that created the `BoundingBox` was trying to set it with an invalid field value.  The specifics of how the `BoundingBox` was getting set to an invalid value are not pertinent or helpful here because they're unique to my situation.

[image]

Comment: Good that you found a solution. You know, Hibernate is open source and you can contribute back improvements to the error reporting, so if you have an idea on how the error can be improved, please don't hesitate to create a pull request for it!